# WIndows 8.1 windows store app sqlite Update statement

Tags: c#, sqlite, winrt-xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I can't put the 'db.update' statement to work. When I try to read the database, it always reads the very first data inserted from the else statement. I have traced my program and it does reach the db.update and the values being passed is correct but when I read the table the values don't change.

I'm making a windows store app in windows 8.1 using Visual Studio 2013

here's my code

```
LastRead dataref = new LastRead { passID = U_pick.chapterID, chapterLastRead = U_pick.chapterNumber, passtitle = mTitle };
        var dbpath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Drive.db");
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
        {
            try
            {
                var lastReadChapter = (db.Table<LastRead>().Where(c => c.passtitle == mTitle)).SingleOrDefault();
                if (lastReadChapter != null)
                {
                    lastReadChapter.chapterLastRead = U_pick.chapterNumber;
                    lastReadChapter.passtitle = U_pick.chapterTitle;
                    lastReadChapter.passID = U_pick.chapterID;
                    db.Update(lastReadChapter);
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Insert(dataref);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //excepetion msg
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're making the query by the SingleOrDefault() function.